# How to resolve issue "Java instances eating up all my memory"

Tags: java, android, memory, ram

I upgraded my `Android Studio` from 4.0 to 4.1 a few weeks ago and since then I am facing this issue that there are a number of instances of `Java` running. Attaching snapshot for reference.
[image]

You can see that there are a number of `Java` instances under `Android Studio` and almost equal instances are outside of `Android Studio` as standalone instances.
I have followed some threads related to this issue and performed:

1. Java Cache Cleanup
2. Uninstall and reinstall Java
3. Restart System

After restarting system it works normally for sometime or for a day then I face the same problem again. Please let me know what I have to do to overcome this problem. After this much memory consumption `Android Studio` does not run the code saying there is not enough memory, So it wastes a lot of time.

I'm using

- Windows 10 - 64-bit
- Java 8 update 281 - 64-bit
- Android Studio 4.1
- 16 GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust JVM options with [org.gradle.jvmargs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:configuring_jvm_memory)
at `gradle.properties` file. For example `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx1536M"`

Comment: I already have used this option and allocated 3GB to JVM. problem is not the size, the problem is instances.